# r function cor.test(): How is the p-value calculated for pearson correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, pearson

It's probably a very easy question.

I can't find the methodology behind the pvalue calculation in the cor.test() function in R.

Comment: The [reference](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347111?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) is provided in `help("cor.test")`. You can also study the source code of `stats:::cor.test.default`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code that calculates the p-value of Pearson's correlation:

```
x <- c(44.4, 45.9, 41.9, 53.3, 44.7, 44.1, 50.7, 45.2, 60.1)
y <- c( 2.6,  3.1,  2.5,  5.0,  3.6,  4.0,  5.2,  2.8,  3.8)
ct = cor.test(x, y, method = "pearson")
ct$p.value  ## this is what cor.test() gives

n <- length(x)
r <- cor(x, y)
df <- n - 2
t = sqrt(df) * r/sqrt(1 - r^2)
pval = 2 * min(pt(t, df), pt(t, df, lower.tail = FALSE))  ## this is calculated manually

ct$p.value == pval
```

Comment: Hi AK88, thank you for your answer. What I'm looking for is the formula behind $p.value.

Comment: The formula behind `p.value` is -- first find the `t-statistic` using the formula `sqrt(df) * r/sqrt(1 - r^2)`. And then extract upper and lower tail probabilities of this `t-statistic`. Take the minimum value from these probabilities and multiply by 2, as we have to take both tails of the distribution. Is this clear?

Comment: can you provide me a source for the formula? I can't find it on the internet.

Comment: Sure, have a look at this topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120199/calculate-p-value-for-the-correlation-coefficient